# Compare C# string with Sql Server decimal type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a scenario that I have string value in c# and in SQL server the data type is decimal and requirement is that i have to filter value like we do in string which includes (startswith,endswith,contains etc) filters. I am trying like this :

```
 customers = customers.Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.CrmCustomerNumber).Contains(value));
```

but it's give me error because you can't use Convert.tostring in IQuerable. I know that I can do that

```
customers.ToList().Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.CrmCustomerNumber).Contains(value));
```

but I am doing Customer.ToList() at the end after applying all filters. is there any solution of my problem?

Comment: Why do such a comparison at all? Just parse the string value into a decimal and compare with the data. You probably misunderstood the requirement anyway - nobody asks you to use the slowest way to query data. Moste likely they asked you to *avoid floating point uncertainty*. Using `System.Decimal` and specifying the correct scale and precision in your SQL Command parameters takes care of that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,it could be that, or it could really be a task to enable quiries like "give us all customers whose IDs in our CRM start with '123' or whose IDs contain '567'". Looks weird to me, but certainly possible. In which case what OP asks for is a valid thing.

Comment: @Anrei not for `startswith`. This would still force a full table scan, when a range query would use the primary key. Besides, this would require an *integer* or bigint, not a decimal. Whatever the *real* requirement is, it can be handled without resorting to full-table scans

Comment: @Imranbutt what is your *actual* problem and why do you think you need the equivalent of `LIKE '%123%` to do it? There's probably another way to do this

Comment: @Andrei or it could be a more serious problem, eg a CSV field instead of a `many-to-many` relation. In this case, redesigning the schema would fix the problem *and* improve performance

Comment: requirement is for instance i have 123.00,123.59,123.80 and 123.75 and if write 123 i have to get all values

Comment: @Imranbutt that's *not* a requirement, that's a bug. You have a list of values, but instead of storing them in a separate table, you stored them as a string field thus breaking even the 1st Normal Form. Now you can't query them and the hacky way to do so is very slow. The real solution is to *fix the buggy table design*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess you didn't get it...there are values of different rows not a value of one row

Comment: @Imranbutt that's because you still haven't explained the *actual* requirement. If you want to find values between 123 and 124 just write the equivalent `Where(..)` statement. What you expressed in the question and comments may be what you think is the solution, not the actual problem.

Comment: Wait, did you actually store *business logic* like a *hierarchy* in the key? Are you asking how to find *children* of a customer category? What you try to do then is supported by the `hierarhcyid` type. Even *without* a hierarchyid, you could find the full key of the *category* then return anything that *starts* with it. This would still benefit from indexing

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are of a known size, for instance if they are all six digits, then you could just query for a value range.

Example: I'm looking for all six-digit numbers that start with 123. That's the same as saying "WHERE Value BETWEEN 123000 AND 123999". So you could query `.Where(x => x >= 123000 && x <= 123999)`.

IF the numbers aren't all a consistent size, but at least have some practical limit, you could extend this to say `.Where(x => x == 123 || (x >= 1230 && x <= 1239) || (x >= 12300 && x <= 12399) || (x >=123000 && x <= 123999)`. etc.

With a little math, you could make this work for any number. `(x >= n * 10 && x <= ((n * 10) + 9))`

EndsWith can be done using modulo math.
Contains... well... you're stuck with a table scan. In that case, you might seriously consider adding a second, perhaps computed column to the table, one that stores the same value as a string, and then indexing that column. Then, use the new column to do the searches.